# How to repair multiply-claimed blocks?

Tags: linux, raid, filesystems, fsck

I get a lot of the following logs in dmesg:

```
[26159.277230] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_iget:3875: inode #394497188: comm mv: bad extended attribute block 22794025699896
[26219.914802] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_iget:3875: inode #394497188: comm rm: bad extended attribute block 22794025699896
[26219.979362] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_iget:3875: inode #394497188: comm rm: bad extended attribute block 22794025699896
[26310.378878] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_iget:3875: inode #394497185: comm rm: bad extended attribute block 57759718172350
[26310.444128] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_iget:3875: inode #394497186: comm rm: bad extended attribute block 162206451263262
[26310.509166] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_iget:3875: inode #394497187: comm rm: bad extended attribute block 219797061798141
[26310.574269] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_iget:3875: inode #394497188: comm rm: bad extended attribute block 22794025699896
[26310.639499] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_iget:3875: inode #394497189: comm rm: bad extended attribute block 276433459229836
[26310.704830] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_iget:3875: inode #394497190: comm rm: bad extended attribute block 122783965770376
[26310.770272] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_iget:3875: inode #394497191: comm rm: bad extended attribute block 275806918528226
[26310.836024] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_iget:3875: inode #394497192: comm rm: bad extended attribute block 14876582473268
[26310.901775] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_iget:3875: inode #394497193: comm rm: bad extended attribute block 266647592419907
[26310.967680] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_lookup:1044: inode #394472149: comm rm: deleted inode referenced: 394497194
....
```

followed by

```
[432047.072017] EXT4-fs (sdb1): error count: 127466
[432047.072020] EXT4-fs (sdb1): initial error at 1430213419: ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739
[432047.072024] EXT4-fs (sdb1): last error at 1434663035: ext4_iget:3875: inode 394497616
[434896.488164] EXT4-fs (sdb1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[484610.455623] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:587: inode #404544002: block 6422531607: comm updatedb.mlocat: bad entry in directory: directory entry across blocks - offset=0(0), inode=540226868, rec_len=11824, name_len=54
```

fsck gives me the following output:

```
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 7697183 has an invalid extent node (blk 122161590, lblk 0)
Clear? yes

Inode 7697183, i_blocks is 704, should be 0.  Fix? yes

Inode 11592466 has an invalid extent node (blk 184029687, lblk 0)
Clear? yes

Inode 11592466, i_blocks is 265176, should be 0.  Fix? yes

Inode 11592467 has an invalid extent node (blk 184029688, lblk 0)
Clear? yes

Inode 11592467, i_blocks is 265176, should be 0.  Fix? yes

Inode 11592468 has an invalid extent node (blk 184029689, lblk 0)
Clear? yes

[...]

Running additional passes to resolve blocks claimed by more than one inode...
Pass 1B: Rescanning for multiply-claimed blocks
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 2: 7167
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 8: 7172 7169 7170 7173 7179 7180 7184 86548858 7186 7194 7197 7200 86562277 86563835 7203 86569985 7207 86571589 7209
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 11: 7210 6279 6280
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 99118: 1740354
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 99351: 1610277
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 99665: 1610924
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 99811: 1611233
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 99876: 7213
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 99887: 1611380
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 99913: 1611444
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 99959: 1611562
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 99976: 1611598
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 99981: 1611584
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 99997: 1611609

[...]
Pass 1C: Scanning directories for inodes with multiply-claimed blocks
Pass 1D: Reconciling multiply-claimed blocks
File /project/iwslt2014c/euronews2014_IT_TR/TR/05.mary.nn.EN.2/system/Logs/log.samples.44.i13hpc27.44.86445 (inode #6902170, mod time Tue Jan 20 14:27:44 2015) 
  has 1 multiply-claimed block(s), shared with 1 file(s):
        /project/mtqt/project/wmt15/ende/temp/4262.log (inode #394497188, mod time Mon Jul 27 23:06:33 2105)
Clone multiply-claimed blocks? yes

File /project/iwslt2014c/euronews2014_IT_TR/TR/05.mary.nn.EN.2/system/Logs/log.samples.52.i13hpc27.52.86445 (inode #6902187, mod time Tue Jan 20 14:27:46 2015) 
  has 1 multiply-claimed block(s), shared with 1 file(s):
        /project/mtqt/project/wmt15/ende/temp/4262.log (inode #394497188, mod time Mon Jul 27 23:06:33 2105)
Clone multiply-claimed blocks? yes

File /project/iwslt2014c/euronews2014_IT_TR/TR/05.mary.nn.EN.2/system/Logs/log.samples.54.i13hpc27.54.86445 (inode #6902191, mod time Tue Jan 20 14:27:43 2015) 
  has 1 multiply-claimed block(s), shared with 1 file(s):
        /project/mtqt/project/wmt15/ende/temp/4262.log (inode #394497188, mod time Mon Jul 27 23:06:33 2105)
Clone multiply-claimed blocks? yes

[...]
```

The output of fsck is huge. Especially section 1B, where it lists all the multiply claimed blocks, fills several GB. And this leads to the problem that fsck runs way too long, so I couldn't let it finish. But so far it seemed as if the problem concentrates one single temporary log file (`/project/mtqt/project/wmt15/ende/temp/4262.log`), that I unfortunately cannot delete (IO Error).

I get similar error on a similar server, using the same RAID controller (LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2208 [Thunderbolt] (rev 05)). So I suspect, that maybe there is a setup problem with the RAID controller.

What can I do, to get rid of this problem? Would it make sense, to simply make a backup of everything and then reformat and restore? Or is there a more eloquent solution? Can I somehow get rid of this one logfile, that seems to cause the trouble? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: "Multiply claimed blocks" means two files think some block both belong to them. This means guaranteed data loss, even if you can repair the filesystem. At this point, there is no "make a backup"; you should have done that already. You will have to restore from a backup that already exists.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks. Unfortunately we don't have a backup. But we could probably live with losing the affected files. The question is how can we save as much as possible and restore the filesystem, so that it is without errors.